# How to get result?

Tags: objective-c

hello! Sorry for my question. I hope you'll ask and help me.

I want to get result with this code:

```
NSNumber *first = @10;
NSNumber *second = @30;
NSNumber *resultTest = first + second;
```

But Xcode got a error, unfortunately. How to add the variables with class NSNumber?

I know I can with this way:

```
int first = 10;
int second = 20;
int result = first + second;
```

But how to do it with class NSNumber?

Sorry again. I am newbie in Objective-C programming. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use `NSNumber` for this?

Comment: and your xcode error is???

Comment: It doesn't matter. In my tutorial uses NSNumber :)

Comment: @TagirNagumanov It does matter. No one would deliberately create two `NSNumber` objects just for the sake of adding them together (except as a learning exercise). But you may need to get two numbers from a collection. In that case you will have two `NSNumber` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `NSNumber` to `int`, sum the numbers, then convert back to `NSNumber`.

```
NSNumber *result = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([first intValue] + [second intValue])];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSNumber` isn't designed to be used in calculations. It's main usage is to wrap primitive (numeric) types so that they can be used in contexts where you need an object---typically for storing them in a collection such as an `NSArray`.

That being said, the following will work:

```
NSNumber *first = @10;
NSNumber *second = @30;

NSNumber *third = @([first integerValue] + [second integerValue]);
```